# Find sum distance to horizontal line for all points in Matlab

Tags: matlab, conditional-statements

I have a scatter plot of approximately 30,000 pts, all of which lie above a horizontal line which I've visually defined in my plot. My goal now is to sum the vertical distance of all of these points to this horizontal line.

The data was read in from a `.csv` file and is already saved to the workspace, but I also need to check whether a value is `NaN`, and ignore these.

This is where I'm at right now:

```
vert_deviation = 0;
idx = 1;
while idx <= numel(my_data(:,5)) && isnan(idx) == 0
    vert_deviation = vert_deviation + ((my_data(idx,5) - horiz_line_y_val));
    idx = idx + 1;
end
```

I know that a prerequisite of using the `&&` operator is having two `logical` statements I believe, but I'm not sure how to rewrite this loop in this way at the moment. I also don't understant why `vert_deviation` returns `NaN` at the moment, but I assume this might have to do with the first mistake I described...

I would really appreciate some guidance here - thank you in advance!

EDIT: The 'horizontal line' is a slight oversimplification - in reality the lower limit I need to find the distance to consists of 6 different line segments

Comment: How about a single sum: `vert_deviation = sum(((my_data(:,5) - horiz_line_y_val)), 'omitnan');`?

Comment: Thank you for your response - the code you posted worked fine, but I should have specified that the horizontal line was a simplification - in reality the lower limit changes for different parts of the plot and I need to check to see which range of x values a given pt on the scatter plot falls into.

Comment: The please [edit] the question to contain a true [mcve], and not an oversimplification.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the information you wrote below. The space below is reserved for answers to the question you posted, not for answers to comments.

Comment: It is a solution to the question I posted, thus I uploaded it as an answer. The clarification was added as in the OP as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have specified that the lower limit to which I need to calculate the distance for all scatterplot points varies for different x values (the horizontal line snippet was meant to be a simplification but may have been misleading... apologies for that)

I first modified the data I had already read into the workspace by replacing all `NaN`values with `0`. Next, I wrote a `while` loop which defines the number if indexes to loop through, and defined an `&&` condition to filter out any zeroes. I then wrote a nested `if` loop which checks what range of x values the given index falls into, and subsequently takes the delta between the y values of a linear line lower limit for that section of the plot and the given point. I repeated this for all points.

```
while idx <= numel(my_data(:,3)) && not(my_data(idx,3) == 0)
    ...
    if my_data(idx,3) < upper_x_lim && my_data(idx,5) > lower_x_lim
        vert_deviation = vert_deviation + (my_data(idx,4) - (m6 * (my_data(idx,5)) + b6))
    end
    ...
```

`m6` and `b6` in this case are the slope and y intercept calculated for one section of the plot. The `if` loop is repeated six times for each section of the lower limit.

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this, so I'm open to any feedback if there's room for improvement!

Comment: Is this an answer to your own question or is it a clarification? If a clarification, please delete this answer and update your question instead.

Comment: This is not a clarification. This is a solution to the issue described in my question which works.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop doesn't exclude NaN values becuase `isnan(idx) == 0` checks to see if the index is NaN, rather than checking if the data point is NaN. Instead, check for `isnan(my_data(idx,5))`.

---

Also, you can simplify your code using `for` instead of `while`:

```matlab
vert_deviation = 0;
for idx=1:size(my_data,1)
   if !isnan(my_data(idx,5))
      vert_deviation = vert_deviation + ((my_data(idx,5) - horiz_line_y_val));
   end
end
```

As [@Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59627180/find-sum-distance-to-horizontal-line-for-all-points-in-matlab#comment105416609_59627180) suggested, you can remove the loop altogether, but it seems that the code in the OP is an oversimplification of the problem. Looking at the additional code posted, I guess it is still possible to remove the loops, but I'm not certain it will be a significant speed improvement. Just use a loop.